# It's possible connect to a computer to control the mouse or keyboard?

Tags: windows, linux, networking, mouse

I want to know if there is some default service in Windows/Linux/etc where I can connect from a remote computer (the same network) to control the mouse.

The main point is if I can do this without the need of installing a new server program on the machine.

**Edit:** I know tools like VNC. This question is only for developing purposes, and not a real need of remote control.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default installed program on the mentioned platforms that will do this.

However, there are a lot of cross platform vnc programs out there that are free if that's your concern.  I personally use:

http://www.tightvnc.com/

If you just want to control the mouse and can still see the screen via another method, I use the following to do that.  It works well and is cross platform (and free):

http://synergy-foss.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second option (synergy) in Daren's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7830373/868718) and you want to use Windows 7 machine as the server and linux client, then I have a couple tips that may help.  I'm new to linux, but have it working now so I can control my linux laptop using my windows 7 keyboard/mouse and Synergy.

1. Run "hostname" on windows powershell to get correct server name. Setup the server with the screenname set in step 2 below.
2. used the following command in ubuntu linux shell:

   ```
   synergyc -f -n linux WINDOWSHOSTNAME.local
   ```

The -f is not necessary probably. I used -n to avoid having to type in a long hostname in the server setup and just names my linux screen "linux."  You can use whatever you want.